# What simulator is appropriate for modeling intrusion detection and prevention in large-scale static wireless sensor networks and simulated attacks?

Tags: sensors, security, wireless

When it comes to simulating intrusion detection and prevention in large-scale static WSNs, the choice of simulator is crucial. These networks, comprising stationary sensors (independent low-power computing units), often face various types of attacks that can compromise their security. Factors like the network's scale, the specific types of attacks to be simulated, and the accuracy required in modelling the network's behaviour have to be considered.

To my knowledge, simulators like NS-3 (Network Simulator 3) and OMNeT++ are commonly used for modelling WSNs. Maybe Cooja (Contiki) is another suitable candidate. My goal would be to simulate networks containing 50 up to 100 nodes (if realistic?).

However, for specifically simulating intrusion detection and prevention systems within large-scale static wireless sensor networks, simulators that provide modules or extensions dedicated to security protocols and attack simulations become essential. These specialised simulators often allow for a more detailed and accurate representation of the network's security mechanisms and potential vulnerabilities.

I am intending to replicate and test the following collaborative security framework for WSNs: [Antilizer: run time self-healing security for wireless sensor networks](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3286978.3287029?casa_token=Ec0JDXKGrKMAAAAA:Oq2ULweQFznBgPk4ltKEI_kzNZhgr0SWlg5aLUsMwxDN3_fM7HGnWta4FA8dof5UL4eGmyvsaSnr)

I am open to suggestions on how to get started most efficiently, to achieve my final project goal.

Personal background: I have no practical experience with the development of WSNs or their simulation. The programming language I am most familiar with is Python, 6 years ago I was very experienced with Java but haven't touched it since. I have some experience with C/C++ (~98) and two years ago I've learned Rust and forgot it again because the project I've learned it for never took place.